# how to remove li span via jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i remove the span element  via jquery?

I cannot count on li id selector because all ol is being built dynamically

```
<div class="on">
    <ol id="selectable" class="ui-selectable">
        <li id="11_3_6" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">11.3.6</li>
        <li id="10_3_16" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">10.3.16</li>
        <li id="11_2_26" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee ui-selected">11.2.26<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span></li>
        <li id="9_1_53" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">9.1.53</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I don't want to remove the entire li. just the span

Comment: `$('#selectable li span.ui-icon ').remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do...

```
$("li span").remove();
```

Comment: i don't want to remove all li just the span

Comment: Bear in mind it will remove any spans that are descendants of any li element so you may want to narrow that down a bit by adding to the criteria...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to remove the span from the li element, try this:

`$(".on > ol > li > span").remove()`

Answer (score 0):

$('div.on ol.selectable li span').remove();

this will remove span element and its content from your HTML. always use specific element with id while removing otherwise it might remove others also.